# coldfusion 11 Search Filtering

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to accomplish a Search Filtering system in ColdFusion 11 and I am not sure the way around this, if there was a plugin then even better.
eg:
http://www.pcworld.co.uk/gbuk/search-keywords/xx_xx_xx_xx_xx/mouse/xx-criteria.html

I am trying to achieve the sub filters on the left, I have tried playing about with queries of queries but with URL strings etc its getting messy.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: pcworld is almost certainly using something like Elastic Search to do the aggregations.

Comment: What is elastic search?

Comment: full-text search engine https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch which does term aggregation (which is what you're talking about).